# Knockout JS autosave ratelimit

Tags: knockout.js

Here's a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/pqs142aw/

I'd like to auto save when the user stops their changes.  The problem I have is that the check for ko.computedContext.isInitial() only occurs during the initial page load and doesn't fire after changes to observables are made.

```
ko.computed(function () {
    var isInitial = ko.computedContext.isInitial();               
    if (isInitial) {
        console.log("init...");                         
    }
    else { 
       //doesn't get called
       console.log("saving...");            
       self.save(); 

    }}, self).extend({ rateLimit: { timeout: 1000, method: "notifyWhenChangesStop" } });
```

How can I get this to work or is there a better way?

Comment: Updated fiddle <https://jsfiddle.net/pqs142aw/1/>.  This will auto save after changes are stopped but it also fires on initial page load which I don't want.

Answer (score 1):

I changed a few things to demonstrate how you could make this work:

- Some inputs, a computed and a constant were added to show how this would scale.
- The `viewModel` computed is changed to return a json string of the entire object except this `viewModel` computed. The routine `ko.JS` loops through all the observables so from now on, when any of the observables change, the computed is triggered.
- A subscription is added to this computed to call save when the computed is triggered.

Have a look at the example below:

```js
var ViewModel = function() {
  var self = this;
  self.id = 1234;
  self.firstname = ko.observable();
  self.prefix = ko.observable();
  self.lastname = ko.observable();
  self.fullname = ko.computed(function() {
    return `${self.firstname() || ''} ${self.prefix() || ''} ${self.lastname() || ''}`
  });

  self.save = function(json) {
    console.log(`saved... ${json}`);
  };

  self.viewModel = ko.computed(function() {
    var vm = ko.toJS(self);
    delete vm.viewModel;
    return JSON.stringify(vm);
  }).extend({ rateLimit: { timeout: 1000, method: "notifyWhenChangesStop" } });

  self.viewModel.subscribe(function(json) {
    self.save(json);
  });
};

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<p>Id: <span data-bind='text: id'></span></p>
<p>Firstname: <input data-bind='textInput: firstname' /></p>
<p>Firstname: <input data-bind='textInput: prefix' /></p>
<p>Lastname: <input data-bind='textInput: lastname' /></p>
<p>Fullname: <span data-bind='text: fullname'></span></p>
```

Comment: Thanks appreciate the reply.  So I need to specify in the computed all the observables/properties which need to be saved?  For example, if I had a form with 25+ inputs I would need specify all these?  Is there a more efficient way of doing this?

Comment: You're right. This didn't scale well. I updated the answer with a new example containing an extra input, a computed and a constant.

Answer (score 0):

I got this to work for me updated fiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/qLu6jnmy/.

```
    ko.dirtyFlag = function (root, isInitiallyDirty) {
        var result = function () { },
            _initialState = ko.observable(ko.toJSON(root)),
            _isInitiallyDirty = ko.observable(isInitiallyDirty);

        result.isDirty = ko.computed(function () {
            return _isInitiallyDirty() || _initialState() !== ko.toJSON(root);
        });

        result.reset = function () {
            _initialState(ko.toJSON(root));
            _isInitiallyDirty(false);
        };

        return result;
    };

var ViewModel = function () {
            var self = this;                        
            self.firstName = ko.observable();
            self.middleName = ko.observable();
            self.lastName = ko.observable();
            self.dirtyFlag = new ko.dirtyFlag(self);           

            self.save = function () {
                const viewModelToJson = ko.toJSON(self); 
                console.log("saved...");                    
            };
 
            ko.computed(function () {
                if (self.dirtyFlag.isDirty()) {
                    self.save();
                    self.dirtyFlag.reset();
                }
            }).extend({ rateLimit: { timeout: 1000, method: "notifyWhenChangesStop" } });
        };
        
        var vm = new ViewModel();            
        ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

One key piece was from this post http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/05/creating-smart-dirty-flag-in-knockoutjs.html which explains how to implement a generic dirty flag.